# How to locally deploy Eth 2.0 and try out its APIs?

Tags: proof-of-stake

How to locally deploy Eth 2.0 and try out its APIs?

What to download/build/run to get the latest collection of Etherium 2.0 features (PoS, Layer 2 scaling)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment so Im leaving this answer. Check [Eth 2 documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/get-involved/) and pick one ofthe clients, then you can download from their doucmentation and run your own local node.

For example if you choose to tu use `Lodestar` you might get to this [page](https://chainsafe.github.io/lodestar/usage/testnet/) where you can learn how to run your own local node pointing to the Beacon Chain(the eth2.0 chain)